# Substituting Column Values From Other Columns On The Fly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want the contents of a query to land in an Excel sheet, the data flow already applied in SSIS.

Th query is trying to achieve a set of values to appear in one column using values from other columns in the same table.

Example:

```
Case When col_date1 > 1900 then col_date1
     When col_date1 = '' and col_date2 like 18% then col_date3
     Else col_date4
End
```

Usually the col_date values are hardcoded strings but in my case I want them to be values from the other columns dynamically applied as the query runs and stores the output into Excel.

i don't think an `Update` statement works here because that would permenantly change the conents of the table which I'm trying to avoid. The changes should take effect on the fly and land in Excel while leaving the SQL Server table unchanged.

Perhaps a `left join` somehow but not sure that works either.

Any ideas?

Comment: the case you are showing could do this, what is the problem with it ?

Comment: From what table/columns would the 1900 and '' and 18% come from?  if there is 1 record containing all those values (or 1 record could be constructed) you could just `cross join (Select val1, val2, val3 from tbl)` and substitute the val1, val2, val3 in for 1900, '' and 18%.  this only howrks if the result from the query is 1 RECORD and always is 1 record.

Comment: The string for a like statement should be in single quotes `LIKE '18%'`

Comment: @SSingh could you please add sample input and output data, that will help to clarify the goal